# PHP cURL to scrape ASPX no data shown

Tags: php, asp.net, ajax, curl

I'm trying to scrape this page with php cURL: http://www.newhorizonssc.com/localweb/catalog/coursecatalog.aspx?GroupId=402&keyword=infopath

However when I run that url through cURL and echo the results, I get the outline of the page, however the table of data in the middle of the page is missing.

Result of just going to url in browser:
[image: Good result]

Result of after running url through cURL:
[image: Bad results]

However, the result with the blank area is also what I see when I look at the HTML of the request in Firebug for the good page (so maybe my headers are good if it matches this?):
[image: headers]

So obviously I cannot scrape the data from the table when it's not showing up.

I've been trying all day, going through questions asked on here, tutorials that were linked, Google.  It's obvious that accessing data with php cURL and aspx forms is not the easiest, however nothing has worked.

First I would think that since I can just add "?GroupId=402&keyword=infopath" to the end of the URL, that a simple GET would work.  However since it's not, I assume that there has to be some sort of validation or something going on.

I'm pretty sure that I have all the correct header information.  However I noticed that on the page that spits out the good results, there are 24 XHR requests, on my page with cURL there are 0.  I'm thinking that somehow I'm supposed to be making an AJAX call to bring up that table, but I'm pretty lost on how to do that.
---Also if I ever do get this table to display, I also need to make an ajax call to simulate clicking the little plus button, which makes an ajax call and displays the list of classes under each course.

Here is my entire cURL function I'm using:

```
private function __curl($url) {    
                    $nameCourseSearch='ctl00$uxContentBody$txtSearch';
                    $valCourseSearch = 'infopath';
                    $nameSearchBtn = 'ctl00$uxContentBody$btnSearch';
                    $valSearchBtn = 'GO';


                    // the path to a file we can read/write; this will
                    // store cookies we need for accessing secured pages
                    $cookieFile = 'cookie.txt';

                    // regular expressions to parse out the special ASP.NET
                    // values for __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION
                    $regexViewstate = '/__VIEWSTATE\" value=\"(.*)\"/i';
                    $regexEventVal  = '/__EVENTVALIDATION\" value=\"(.*)\"/i';


                    /************************************************
                    * utility function: regexExtract
                    *    use the given regular expression to extract
                    *    a value from the given text;  $regs will
                    *    be set to an array of all group values
                    *    (assuming a match) and the nthValue item
                    *    from the array is returned as a string
                    ************************************************/
                    function regexExtract($text, $regex, $regs, $nthValue)
                    {
                    if (preg_match($regex, $text, $regs)) {
                     $result = $regs[$nthValue];
                    }
                    else {
                     $result = "";
                    }
                    return $result;
                    }


        $ch = curl_init();


                    /************************************************
                    * first, issue a GET call to the ASP.NET login
                    *   page.  This is necessary to retrieve the
                    *   __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION values
                    *   that the server issues
                    ************************************************/
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
                    $data=curl_exec($ch);

                    // from the returned html, parse out the __VIEWSTATE and
                    // __EVENTVALIDATION values
                $viewstate = regexExtract($data,$regexViewstate,$regs,1);
                $eventval = regexExtract($data, $regexEventVal,$regs,1);

         $postData =  array(
             '__VIEWSTATE'=>rawurlencode($viewstate),
          '__EVENTVALIDATION'=>rawurlencode($eventval),
             'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tc1_ClientState' => '{&quot;ActiveTabIndex&quot;:0,&quot;TabState&quot;:[true,true]}',                          $nameCourseSearch =>$valCourseSearch,
                 $nameSearchBtn =>$valSearchBtn,
                    );           

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/4");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
        //testing asp options
                curl_setOpt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);
                $data = curl_exec($ch);

                /************************************************
                * with the authentication cookie in the jar,
                * we'll now issue a GET to the secured page;
                * we set curl's COOKIEFILE option to the same
                * file we used for the jar before to ensure the
                * authentication cookie is sent back to the
                * server
                ************************************************/
                curl_setOpt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);   
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile);     

                $data = curl_exec($ch);

        //$result = curl_exec($ch);
        if(!$data) {
            echo "<br />cURL error number: ".curl_errno($ch);
            echo "<br />cURL erro: ".curl_error($ch). " on URL - ". $url;
            var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
            var_dump(curl_error($ch));
            exit;
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

Sorry for this being so long.  Just wanted to make sure I posted all the information I thought was needed.

thanks.

Comment: Maybe those tables are dynamically created via ajax?

Comment: that's what I think. That's why I'm trying to figure out how to make that AJAX call to generate the table.  From what I can tell from reading, it's possible to make that call. I just can't figure out how or where.